# Sinatra: params hash cannot be merged

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to merge a hash with default parameters and the actual parameters given in a request. When I call this seemingly innocent script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
        defaults = { 'p1' => 'default1', 'p2' => 'default2' }
        # params = request.params
        params = defaults.merge(params)
        params
end
```

with `curl http://localhost:4567?p0=request` then it crashes with

```
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
2016-06-17 11:10:34 - TypeError - no implicit conversion of nil into Hash:
        sinatrabug:8:in `merge'
        sinatrabug:8:in `block in <main>'
```

When I access the Rack `request.params` directly it works. I looked into the Sinatra sources but I couldn't figure it out.

So I have a solution for my actual problem. But I don't know *why* it works.

My question is: Why can I assign `param` to a parameter, why is the class `Hash` but in `defaults.merge params` it throws an exception?

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the output of `params.inspect`? Also try appending `.to_h`. Sometimes it works!

Comment: `params.inspect?`returns: `NoMethodError - undefined method `inspect?' for {}:Hash:`. I already tried the `.to_h` method to no avail.

Comment: @SteffenRoller there is no question mark, it should be `params.inspect`

Comment: `params.inspect` returns an empty hash `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the way Ruby handles local variables and setter methods (i.e. methods that end in `=`) with the same name. When Ruby reaches the line

```
params = defaults.merge(params)
```

it assumes you want to create a new local variable named `params`, rather than use the method. The initial value of this variable will be `nil`, and this is the value that the `merge` method sees.

If you want to refer to the method, you need to refer to it as `self.params=`. This is for any object that has such a method, not just Sinatra.

A better solution, to avoid this confusion altogether, might be to use a different name. Something like:

```
get '/' do
  defaults = { 'p1' => 'default1', 'p2' => 'default2' }
  normalized_params = defaults.merge(params)
  normalized_params.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is throwing an error because `params` is `nil` when you make this call `defaults.merge(params)`. I assume you are trying to merge `defaults` with `request.params`, which should contain the parameters from your GET.

Change this line

```
params = defaults.merge(params)
```

to this

```
params = defaults.merge(request.params)
```

Comment: Yes, the log clearly says that it's `nil`. Therefore I switched to `reuquest.params`. It's line #7 in the script of my question. I thought somebody could tell me *why*. Because I can assign `params` to a variable and print that variable which is not `nil`. I guess there is something going on behind the scenes which I was hoping somebody here could explain.

Comment: Yeah I'm baffled. If you reference `params` on the RHS **without** calling  a method on it, it resolves to `request.params`. But if you do make a method call on the RHS then Ruby assumes `params` is `nil`. Almost seems like a bug in Ruby...

Comment: I suspect it's not Ruby but perhaps Sinatra or Rack.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in rack gem

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request#params-instance_method

It seems you can retrieve GET and POST data by `params` method but you can't write in it. You have to use `update_param` and `delete_param` instead.

Comment: That's not really true though because if you do this `params = defaults.merge(request.params)` it works just fine.